# still want to read filenames in react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code:

> export default function mainScreen({navigation}) {
> const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
>
> const fs = require('react-native-fs');
> const dir = '../assets/images';
>
> fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
> console.log(files.length);
> console.log(err)
> });

my errormessage is the following:

> Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-fs\FS.common.js", which threw an exception: >Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following steps, could be helpful

1. npm i react-native-reanimated
2. cd ios && pod install

After that run the app again.